# extracting column attribute inside a function

Tags: r, ggplot2, attr

Say I have the following tibble:

```
df1 <- structure(list(var1 = structure(c("Didn't do a thing", "Almost did a thing", 
"Once did a thing", "Have never done a thing", "Always do a thing"
), description = "This is the question i asked respondents (and the title of the plot)"), 
    wtd_pct = c(4L, 15L, 62L, 11L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to make a plot function that takes as inputs the name of the tibble (`df1`) and the name of a column inside it (in this case, there is only `var1`, but in my actual tibble I have many more columns).

Inside the plot function I want to pull out the attribute connected to `var1` and make that the plot title. For example, outside a function this looks like this:

```
df1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = var1, x = wtd_pct)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = var1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(wtd_pct, 0), "%")), size = 3.5, vjust = -.5, hjust = -.3, color = 'black') +
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(y = "", 
       x = "Weighted percent", 
       title = paste0("\"", str_wrap(attr(df1$var1, "description"), 100), "\""))
```

Note the `title` line above. However, when I put this inside a function and attempt to call it I get all sorts of errors. E.g.

```
plot_function <- function(.x, .y){
.x %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = {{.y}}, x = wtd_pct)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = {{.y}})) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(wtd_pct, 0), "%")), size = 3.5, vjust = -.5, hjust = -.3, color = 'black') +
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(y = "", 
       x = "Weighted percent", 
       title = paste0("\"", str_wrap(attr({{.x$.y}}, "description"), 100), "\""))
}

plot_function(df1, var1)
```

This returns the plot but with no title + the error `Warning message: Unknown or uninitialised column:` .y`.`. I've tried various other things (wrapping in `!!ensym()`, `.data[[]]`, extracting the attribute first into a separate string, etc., but I never get what I want.

It seems the crux of the issue is that you can't pipe df into `attr()`, but it also doesn't like the `.x$.y` syntax. Can anyone here point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` operator uses non-standard evaluation without substituting, so `.x$.y` will be interpreted as "the column called `.y` inside `df1`", which of course does not exist.

The usual way round this is to use `[[` instead of `$`, but this is a little trickier here because you want to pass an unquoted column name.

One option is to use `.x[[deparse(substitute(.y))]]` (without the curly-curly operators)

```r
plot_function <- function(.x, .y){
  .x %>% 
    ggplot(aes(y = {{.y}}, x = wtd_pct)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = {{.y}})) +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(wtd_pct, 0), "%")), 
              size = 3.5, vjust = -.5, hjust = -.3, color = 'black') +
    theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(y = "", 
         x = "Weighted percent", 
         title = paste0("\"", str_wrap(attr(.x[[deparse(substitute(.y))]],
                                            "description"), 100), "\""))
}

plot_function(df1, var1)
```

[image]

A pure tidyverse equivalent might be to use something like

```r
rlang::eval_tidy(enquo(.y), data = .x)
```

in place of `.x[[deparse(substitute(.y))]]`

Comment: Wonderful Allan. I would never have figured this out on my own (I can confirm it works for my use case, and i'm now on a rabbit hole looking up `deparse` and `substitute`). Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use [pull](https://rdrr.io/github/tidyverse/dplyr/man/pull.html) replacing `{{.x$.y}}` with `pull(.x, {{.y}})` as shown in the line marked ## below.  Also note that all `library` statements should be provided when posting to SO.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

plot_function <- function(.x, .y) {
  .x %>% 
    ggplot(aes(y = {{.y}}, x = wtd_pct)) +
      geom_col(aes(fill = {{.y}})) +
      geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(wtd_pct, 0), "%")), size = 3.5, 
        vjust = -.5, hjust = -.3, color = 'black') +
      theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(y = "", 
        x = "Weighted percent", 
        title = paste0(
          "\"", 
          str_wrap(attr(pull(.x, {{.y}}), "description"), 100), ##
          "\"")
      ) 
}

plot_function(df1, var1)
```

or we might want to rewrite the `title=` part as a pipeline and move to `sprintf` to make it a bit easier to read.

```
plot_function <- function(.x, .y) {
  .x %>% 
    ggplot(aes(y = {{.y}}, x = wtd_pct)) +
      geom_col(aes(fill = {{.y}})) +
      geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(wtd_pct, 0), "%")), size = 3.5, 
        vjust = -.5, hjust = -.3, color = 'black') +
      theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(y = "", 
        x = "Weighted percent", 
        title = pull(.x, {{.y}}) %>%          ##
                  attr("description") %>%     ##
                  str_wrap(100) %>%           ##
                  sprintf('"%s"', .)          ##


      ) 
}

plot_function(df1, var1)
```

[image: screenshot]